# Limit points of a sphere in euclidean space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $S[a,r]=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid \|x-a\|=r\}$ with $r \gt 0$ be a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for each $k\in\ S[a,r]$ i'm trying to find a sequence $k_n$ in $S[a,r] - \{k\}$ converging to $k$. Can someone help me?

I had sucess finding all limit points of the open and closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ using the fact that $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and $\mathbb{(R-Q})^n$ are both dense sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but the sphere is causing me trouble.

Comment: Please review [ask].  You should provide more of a setup to your problem, as it is unclear whether you mean the point belonging to "a sphere" is a limit point of the Euclidean space or a limit point of the subspace consisting of the sphere alone.  Also see [how to post using MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ for mathematical notation.

Comment: subspace consisting of the sphere alone.

Comment: You need to exclude the zero-dimensional sphere $S^0 = \{ -1, 1\}$, those points are isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dieter Fischer has remarked we have to assume $n\geq2$. Up to an obvios similarity we may further assume $a=0$, $r=1$. Given $p\in S^{n-1}$ there is a vector $q\in S^{n-1}$ with $q\perp p$. The sequence
$$x_n:=\cos{1\over n}\ p+\sin{1\over n}\ q\in S^{n-1}\setminus\{p\}\qquad(n\geq1)$$
converges to $p$ as desired.

Comment: this really works, beautiful indeed!